# Series using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a start and end number.divide the number between start and end by 4 equal parts, and print its 10s power. Example if start =110, end=1234

the result should be

```
300
600
900 
1000
```

start and end variable may change. Is that possible to do in jquery or javascript?
i have done the coding

```
    start=43;
    end=194299;
    range=5;
    diff=(end-start)/range;
    value=start;

     while (value < end)
        {
          value += diff;
          log_10 =  parseInt(Math.log(value) / Math.log(10));
          basePower =  Math.pow(10, log_10); 
          result =  parseInt((value/basePower) * basePower); 

         alert(result);
        }
    but its output is like
```

38898
77749
116599
155449
194299
it is not rounded to 10s or 100s or 1000s place

Comment: Yes, please try coding.

Comment: of course. show you code and explain at what point you are stuck

Comment: @atmd please check code

Comment: @Raptor here is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 start=43;
            end=194299;
            range=5;
            diff=(end-start)/range;
            value=start;


             while (value < end)
                {
                  value += diff;
                  log_10 =  parseInt(Math.log(value) / Math.log(10));
                  basePower =  Math.pow(10, log_10); 
                  result =  parseInt((parseInt(value/basePower))* basePower); 

                }
```

i got it is the complete solution.